# MediaPipe's development stage

Tags: mediapipe

I would like to know in what phase of Development Mediapipe is? Is it in alpha, beta or stable/Production?

I saw in the following website that it is in Alpha stage.
https://pypi.org/project/mediapipe/

[Development stage mentioned in PyPi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Imx6L.png)

Please clarify the Mediapipe's development status.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to [the MediaPipe Solutions documentation](https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/solutions/about#notice), MediaPipe Solutions is in early release:

> The MediaPipe Solutions Preview is an early release that is subject to
> the following limitations: it may have limited support, changes may
> not be compatible with other pre-general availability versions, and
> availability may change without notice.